# How do I detect if a new microphone is available?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, microphone

It appears that if one has a mic available, then one can add an event listener for the StatusEvent. However, this only tells you if the mic has been allowed or disallowed.

What I'd really like to do is detect if the static Microphone.names property changes. I would have expected this property to be bindable.

If I right click and select "settings" immediately after plugging in a mic, I can see that flash has updated their list of available microphones. However, there seems to be no way in code for me to receive the same update.

The docs say "Calling Microphone.names requires an extensive examination of the hardware, and it may take several seconds to build the array." So I think polling this every few seconds is not a feasible option.

Comment: I didn't think the runtimes (Flash or AIR) expose this information. I would expect if, after plugging in a new mic, you re-check; the new mic would be found.  But, I don't expect AIR or Flash to tell you that this system detail had changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a little test script:

```
var ta:TextArea = new TextArea();
    ta.width = ta.height = 500;
    addChild(ta);
    var t:Timer = new Timer(5000);
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:Event):void{
        var t0:uint = getTimer();

        var m:* = Microphone.getMicrophone();

        ta.text += "mic found: "+(m?true:false)+" "+(getTimer()-t0);

        t0 = getTimer();
        var o:* = Microphone.names;
        ta.text += "\t\ttime to get names: "+(getTimer()-t0)+"\n";

    });
    t.start();
```

The results were all times with fewer than 10ms (getMicrophone was 0-3ms, names was 2-9ms), which seems pretty fast to me. I don't know, perhaps it's my computer, but it doesn't seem to be too intensive. As getMicrophone is all I need, there are no official warnings about its use, and it's marginally faster, I'm going to poll getMicrophone every few seconds or so to deal with this.

If anyone here cares to run this script and give some feedback on your results, it may help me and others make a better choice.

Comment: you're right, the polling wouldn't take long long to operate, especially at a 5 second interval.  However, I did -1 for taking the idea of the other answers and just answering yourself.

Comment: I was simply trying to make this thread most useful for anyone reading it. Neither your nor joanllenas answers were wholly right, in my opinion, so marking them as correct would have been confusing. If there is a better way to achieve this, then please tell me.

This is not an ego competition. Marking answers down because you don't like the person that answered is not going to be helpful for this community.

Comment: If you wanted to make the thread helpful, you could of commented on the other answers mentioning the polling method and ask to expand on that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can set a change watcher on the 'names' array of Microphone that would actually work because the watcher will only get called if the reference to the array is updated every time (new array).  So this is untested, but something to try:

```
var watcher:ChangeWatcher = ChangeWatcher.watch(Microphone, ['names'], onNameChange);
```

Just need to create the onNameChange handler to see if it's actually being called.  If that doesn't work, then you'll need to do some kind of 'polling' of names every x amount of time.

Answer (score -1):

No events exposed for this matter as you say.
The property is not bindable because Microphone is a Flash player feature, not a Flex Microphone wrapper (as for today binding is Flex only).

I suggest you to poll for Microphone.getMicrophone() every few seconds and assert that is not null. This call is far less "examination intensive" than Microphone.names.

Comment: -1.  Incorrect about Microphone.getMicrophone() and not being able to bind 'flash features'.

Comment: 1. binding is Flex only 2. Microphone is a Flash Player feature.

Comment: Let me explain you why your reply is wrong and why you rated -1 to my answer: ChangeWatcher is flex only because it relies on the Binding mechanism. As I said, Microphone is not a Flex class, it's a Flash Player class and that's why it can't never be wired to the flex binding mechanism. If you wanted to do such thing you'd have to create a wrapper, make a 'names' property [Bindable], poll for the Mic until it's ready and then change the value on 'names'. Then all MicWrapper clients would be notified of the change. I hope that clarifies what I tried to say.